# Scripts to edit a P4 client workspace

Tags: bash, shell, perforce, workspace

I'm writing some script but I need to first get the source code from P4. How do I edit the client workspace in my script?

Here are the steps that I normally take using bash:

```
export P4CLIENT=myworkspace
p4 client
//now I manually edit the source and destination directory using Vim
p4 sync
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why do you need to modify the client each time, rather than just set up the client once and use it?

Comment: I was just wondering if it's possible to do the above task in case I have multiple clients. I will then pass in myworkspace as an argument and execute the script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p4 client` can use standard input and output.

```
export P4CLIENT=myworkspace
p4 client -o > /tmp/myclient.$$ # Write client to a temp file
# Commands to update /tmp/myclient with the changes you need
p4 client -i < /tmp/myclient.$$
p4 sync
rm /tmp/myclient.$$
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question as answered by Barmar, then! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change 98% of my users from "perforce" authentication to "ldap"

I repeated this command for each p4 user:

`((p4 user -o %p4user%) | sed "s/perforce/ldap/g")  | p4 user -i -f`